# Generating 0-10V DAC from 0-5V uC output - Non Inverting Amplifier or VCA?

Tags: amplifier, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer, non-inverting

I want a 0-10 V DAC output but my MCU only has a 0-5 V DAC output. I can't decide which option to go with:

1. Use a Non-Inverting Amplifier circuit (like in the [DS3904 Example](https://www.terraelectronica.ru/%2Fds%2Fpdf%2FD%2FDS3904.pdf))
   [image]

OR

2. Use a voltage controlled gain amplifier like this [TI VCA810](http://www.ti.com/product/VCA810).

Which one would be better?

Comment: Better for what?

Comment: Both will work. One costs pennies, the other is priced at $9.51 each (if you buy 1000). Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the following sentence correctly:

> I want a 0-10 V DAC output but my MCU only has a 0-5 V DAC output.

You "simply" want to amplify the voltage coming from the DAC by a constant gain of 2:1.

So if the output of your DAC is 1.23V you want to have 2.46V at the output of your ciruit?

**Right?**

In this case you require a constant gain, not a variable gain so you neither need a digital potentiometer nor a voltage controlled gain amplifier.

You simply need a non-inverting OPAMP with two constant resistors (in the case of 2:1 both resistors must have the same resistance).

Because most "cheap" OPAMPS do not allow an output "near" the supply voltage you either have to provide a "wider" supply voltage than the output you desire (e.g. -2V and +12V) or you have to use so-called "rail-to-rail" OPAMPS which support an output voltage close to the supply voltage.

**Wrong?**

If you really want to have a CPU controlled gain (e.g. you want to control the volume of an audio amplifier using the CPU) the information in your question is not enough to give you a useful answer.

However there are a few points you should consider:

- Using a non-inverting amplifier

  - your minimum gain will be 1:1 => You cannot have a volume of zero.
  - you need a digital potentiometer
  - you don't need a DAC
  - see the section I have written about "rail-to-rail" OPAMPS above
- Using a voltage controlled amplifier

  - you can have any gain (depending on the IC used)
  - you don't need a digital potentiometer
  - you need a DAC
  - when using VCA810 you need a negative supply voltage
  - when using VCA810 you need -2...0V from the DAC so the DAC output must be amplified using an inverting amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rail to rail amplifier ( gain set to 2). You will also need a 12V or so power supply for the opamp. If you dont have 12V supply, you can use a buck boost converter and convert 5V to 12V.
[here](https://store.ncd.io/product/1-channel-0-10v-dac-digital-analog-converter-i%C2%B2c/) is an example product which does exactly same thing